# Yocto Machine specific variable prepend

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Trying to port some of our recipes to a later version of Yocto (thud).  Under the previous version we'd been able to do something like this:

```
DDD += " A1 "
DDD_prepend += " B2 "
DDD_prepend_mymachine += " C3 "

do_compile () {

echo "  DDD ${DDD}

[...]
}
```

If I built it against "mymachine" I'd get the following:

**DDD   C3  B2   A1**

However in thud it's not prepending the machine specific variable:

**DDD   B2   A1**

What changed and what am I missing?

Thanks!

-Steve

Comment: BTW, there are no upper-case characters in the machine name.

Comment: And no underscore or special character either in the machine name? The next step is to check if `mymachine` is present in `MACHINEOVERRIDES` (or even `OVERRIDES`) by using `bitbake my-recipe -e | grep -e "^MACHINEOVERRIDES="`.

Comment: No underscores or special characters.  I've looked a the MACHINEOVERRIDES again, but it looked correct when looking at it before.  

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found it.  The recipe that was having the issue had the following line:

```
    OVERRIDES = "machine:local"
```

MACHINEOVERRIDES is setting the machine config:

```
    MACHINEOVERRIDES =. "mymachine:
```

Commenting the OVERRIDES line out in the recipe fixed the issue.